# reusing same button for different pages in android

Tags: java, android, xml

The following is my app, I have used listview for button ,hence my xml contains 1 button only and its repeating now i want to go to different pages using that single "details" button ,how i can reuse that button to go for different pages

This is front page of app clicling on text view next page occurs

[image: this is front page of app clicling on text view next page occurs]

This is second image how can i reuse code to go for next pages on different detail button

[image: this is second image how can i reuse code to go for next pages on different detail button]

Comment: Did you  tried `setOnClickListener` method to button.

Answer (score 0):

you can do based on the position of the item clicked. I would suggest you to use recyclerview. anyway you can do something like this.

```
if -> itemclicked position == 1 -> goto page 1
else if -> itemclicked position == 2 -> goto page 2
```

and you alredy get position on the click listener

so there you go..

Answer (score 0):

Heyhey.

The best way, also performance wise would be to use a recyclerview. There is a lot of documentation about that on the internet.

Since I am a beginner I most of the time use Yt tutorial which cut the deal as well.

Since this guy help me a lot I want to make a shout out to him.

[RecyclerView by Mitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vyqz_-sJGFk&t=161s)

He shows you how to use the Recyclerview and with a bit more code on your post I might be able to help you aswell.

Comment: can you mark my post as solved please ;).

Thank you!